# using XSL Transform XML data and their child elements in tabular format HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my test XML in this XML i have child element: INSTRUMENT and sub child element: INSTRUMENT/issuer and could be so on ...

    5002199
    `10001`
     686184SE3

```
<INSTRUMENT>
    <type>FI</type>
    <issuer>
        <FICode>123456</FICode>
        <name>Test</name>
        <city>SF</city>
        <state>CA</state>
    </issuer>

    <issueDate>2011-06-22-05:00</issueDate>
    <maturityDate>2016-06-22-05:00</maturityDate>
    <firstCouponDate>2011-07-22-05:00</firstCouponDate>
    <lastCouponDate>2016-05-22-05:00</lastCouponDate>
    <couponRate>2.0</couponRate>

    <paymentFrequency>12</paymentFrequency>

    <callSchedule>
        <notice>15</notice>
        <timing>0</timing>
        <call id="1">
            <startDate>2011-12-22-05:00</startDate>
            <type>2</type>
            <freq>M</freq>
        </call>
    </callSchedule>
</INSTRUMENT>
<Commision>7.0</Commision>
<price>100.0</price>
```

I want to display this data in HTML tabular form, and run time the xml element could be any thing, so i can't hard code the element or subelement name
i was trying follwinf XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <table border="1" width="1000">
        <tr>
            <td class="section_head">Key</td>
            <td class="section_head">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="*" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

the HTM Child INSTRUMENT and issuer and callSchedule is comming in tabular form
is there any way i can iterate XSL recursivley to create HTML child table for XML child elements ?

Key
        Value
    
    
        ID
        5002199
    
    
        Code
        10001
    
    
        cusip
         686184SE3
    
    
        INSTRUMENT
        FI 123456 Test SF CA 2011-06-22-05:00 2016-06-22-05:00 2011-07-22-05:00 2016-05-22-05:00 2.0 12 15 0 2011-12-22-05:00 100.0 2 M 2012-01-22-05:00 100.0 2012-02-22-05:00 100
    
    
        Commision
        7.0
    
    
        price
        100.0
    
    
        alloc
        100

Comment: Do you want a separate table for the children?

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you are after here. It looks like you want to convert the nodes into name/value pairs and nest the html tables according to the XML hierarchy. Here is a bit of recursion that addresses the problem of not knowing the node names at runtime. Hopefully it well help you get started with this. If it is not what you are looking for you can use it to clarify your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">   
    <html>
      <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </table>  
    </html> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[count(*) = 0]">   
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[count(*) > 0]">  
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>             
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>     
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```